# Spotify API crashing because of Library issue

Tags: android, spotify, libspotify

I had been working with the SpotifyAPI for a long time, but randomly it just started to crash on me whenever it trys to load the player. Here is the error I get

```
12-22 20:20:01.995 28130-28130/com.skyrealm.brockyy.spotifyapi E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.skyrealm.brockyy.spotifyapi-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libgnustl_shared.so"
```

The line of code that I get this error in is

```
Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new Player.InitializationObserver() {
```

Thank you for your time!
- Rockyfish

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have just hit the 64k method limit

This is when the amount of code you have (including libraries) is more than Android usually packs into a dex file aka your apk. *There is a solution*

Try this to resolve the solution:

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

fyi it's sad when you hit this limit :-( and usually there is usused code in your project that could do with pruning to tidy it up (including unused library code).

---

The other possibility is you're writie native (NDK) code, and I can't help you so much with that :)